# Transfer Data from SQL Server to Hadoop

Tags: java, .net, sql-server, hadoop, sqoop

`Sqoop` is the solution But I can't find the `sqoop` solution *(installation & connection to hadoop and SQL Server & transfer of data using sqoop)* for windows. 
**Is there any other way that I can transfer all my data from SQL Server to Hadoop** 
OR
**is there any help regarding use of SQOOP (installation & connection to hadoop and SQL Server & transfer of data using sqoop)** on *windows server 2008 R2*

Comment: Can you give me some more information:
* What Hadoop distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop uses jdbc connections to transfer data from a relational database including ms SQLite server. What command have you executed and what errors or issues are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html
please use this sqoop user guide it might answer your question.

you can sqoop-import to import the data from sql to hadoop.